# What does NBXXXX mean in PRO*C?

Tags: c, proc

I m reading a pro*c source code and I found this line `VARCHAR  EXTCODE[( 14 ) * NBXXXX];` I understand that this is a table but what is the meaning or the value of **NBXXXX** that I can't found a definition about nor in google nor others forums.

I need a minimum understanding is it system constant ? reserved word ? what is this NBXXXX in a simple way ?

Comment: It is *probably* a preprocessor macro defined in a header file, given that it is the convention to declare those in uppercase.  You could `grep` the header files used, or compile with the `-E` option to get the preprocessor intermediate output (redirect stderr to a file) and search that - but beware that it could be very large.

Comment: Assuming that this is a normal C declaration rather than some kind of Pro*C extension, NBXXXX must be either a macro that expands to an integer constant expression, or an `enum` constant.  The `EXTCODE` array will have 14 times (whatever numeric value NBXXXX evaluates to) elements.  It is probably defined in one of the header files that this source file includes. I would recommend searching all of those header files (and the headers that _they_ include, and so on) for the definition.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source code?